# What's the meaning of bits in '/usr/include/c++/4.4/bits/'

Tags: c++, linux, gcc, g++, hierarchy

What's the meaning of bits in '/usr/include/c++/4.4/bits/'

Linux, gcc of course.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The official designation of that folder according to the libstdc++ documentation is:

> "Files included by standard headers
>   and by other files in the bits
>   directory"

Where "bits" probably just means something trivial as "the bits that make up the implementation of what you include via the standard headers".

For example, if you include the standard <algorithm> header, you really include bits/c++config.h, bits/stl_relops.h, bits/stl_pair.h bits/stl_algobase.h and bits/stl_algo.h under the hood, each of which defines the odd bits that alltogether give you what someone including <algorithm> would expect to get.

Boost calls the conceptually same folder "detail".

Comment: "detail" seems more intuitive.

Answer (score 6):

It means that the file is internal to gcc's implementation of the standard library, and you shouldn't include it directly. Where the name "bits" came from, I don't know.

Comment: I think the meaning is that it includes values (bits) that are platform-dependant.